# JS Filter function to remove items in array between two ID's in object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, array-filter

I have a start ID, an end ID and an array of objects like this:

```
var items = [
    {"id":1590464645},
    {"id":1588963781},
    {"id":1587985477},
    {"id":1587986221},
    {"id":1625467428}
],
start_id = 1588963781,
end_id = 1587986221;
```

I would like to filter the array so the `id` in the array that matches the `start_id`, the `id` that matches the `end_id` and all elements in between are removed from the array. In this example only the first and last elements should remain in the filtered array.

```
items = items.filter(function (el) {
  // filter array
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a variable outside of the `filter()` function to keep track of whether or not you're "in" the unwanted group:

```js
var items = [
      {"id" : 1590464645},
      {"id" : 1588963781},
      {"id" : 1587985477},
      {"id" : 1587986221},
      {"id" : 1625467428}
    ],
    start_id = 1588963781,
    end_id = 1587986221,
    inBetween = false;
 
items = items.filter(function (el) {
  if (el.id == start_id)
    {
      inBetween = true;
      return false;
    }
  else if (el.id == end_id)
    {
      inBetween = false;
      return false;
    }
  else
    return ! inBetween;
});

console.log(items);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try slicing until the `start_id` and from the `end_id` until the end of the array

```js
var items = [{
    "id": 1590464645
  }, {
    "id": 1588963781
  }, {
    "id": 1587985477
  }, {
    "id": 1587986221
  }, {
    "id": 1625467428
  }],
  start_id = 1588963781,
  end_id = 1587986221;

var pureIds = items.map(function(item) {
  return item.id;
});

var result =
  items
  .slice(0, pureIds.indexOf(start_id))
  .concat(items.slice(pureIds.indexOf(end_id) + 1, pureIds.length));

console.log(result);
```